# Transforming column headers to values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I want to transform this dataframe :

```
Name    Address   Town   Central1   Central2   Central3   Central4   
Jean    blabla    blabla2    1          2         3           NaN 
James   BLABLA    BLABLA2    5          6         NaN           8
```

to this dataframe :

```
Name    Address   Town      Central    Code     
Jean    blabla    blabla2   Central1     1
Jean    blabla    blabla2   Central2     2
Jean    blabla    blabla2   Central3     3
Jean    blabla    blabla2   Central4     NaN
James   BLABLA    BLABLA2   Central1     5                    
James   BLABLA    BLABLA2   Central2     6
James   BLABLA    BLABLA2   Central3     NaN
James   BLABLA    BLABLA2   Central4     8
```

It's a kind of stack but I don't want to stack all the dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check with `melt`

```
s = df.melt(['Name','Address','Town'],var_name = 'Central',value_name = 'Code')
s
Out[526]: 
    Name Address     Town   Central  Code
0   Jean  blabla  blabla2  Central1   1.0
1  James  BLABLA  BLABLA2  Central1   5.0
2   Jean  blabla  blabla2  Central2   2.0
3  James  BLABLA  BLABLA2  Central2   6.0
4   Jean  blabla  blabla2  Central3   3.0
5  James  BLABLA  BLABLA2  Central3   NaN
6   Jean  blabla  blabla2  Central4   NaN
7  James  BLABLA  BLABLA2  Central4   8.0
```